# Count rows across certain columns in a dataframe if they are greater than another value and groupby another column

Tags: pandas, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'BU': ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'CRS', 'CRS', 'CRS'], 
    'Line_Item': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    '1Q16': [100, 120, 0, 200, 190, 210],
    '2Q16': [100, 0, 130, 200, 190, 210],
    '3Q16': [200, 250, 0, 120, 0, 190]})
```

I wish to count the number of rows in 1Q16, 2Q16, 3Q16 by "BU" that are greater than zero. To count rows in 1Q16, 2Q16, 3Q16 I was just explained, I can use:

```
cols = ['1Q16','2Q16','3Q16']
df[cols].gt(0).sum()
```

In addition, I want to group them by BU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
cols = ['1Q16','2Q16','3Q16']
df[cols].gt(0).groupby(df['BU']).sum()
```

Output will be as follows:

```
      1Q16  2Q16    3Q16
BU          
CRS   3.0   3.0     2.0
Total 2.0   2.0     2.0
```

***Explanation:*** Following is detailed explanation for above.

- Creating `cols` list which has columns names in it where we want to perform tasks.
- Using `gt` function to get values which are more than `0` in mentioned cols.
- Then using `groupby` and passing `df['BU']` to get groupby values related to BU column.
- Then applying `sum` function to get total sum of values greater than `0`.